# SSH to machines on same domain without typing fqdn

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

I use to be able to ssh to my other machines by simply typing `ssh server1` instead of `ssh server1.example.com`. Now I get an error `SSH: Could not resolve hostname server1: Temporary failure in name resolution`. The same error occurs when I ping the short name.

My computers:

- Home computer: home.example.com running Ubuntu 20.04
- Server 1 (runs nameserver, web host): server1.example.com
- Server 2 (runs nameserver 2): server2.example.com

There are a few others, but you get the gist.

My home computer has it's DNS set to use the IP for server1 and server2.

My question, why am I no longer able to ssh/ping short name?

What do I need to adjust to set this back up?

Note: I have never altered the `~/.ssh/config` file, so I don't believe the solution requires editing it.

Comment: Are you able to do an nslookup against the NS servers for the A record `server1` and `server1.example.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the line `search example.com` in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Typically the local domain will be searched automatically, but if that is not `example.com`, you'd experience what you described in the question.

Comment: Thanks Christopher H and tetech. Using Christopher H's suggestion I ran:
nslookup server3 server1.example.com
It returned 'server can't find server1.modem'
I had no idea where the 'modem' domain was set as I don't believe I set it. It wasn't in /etc/hosts or /etc/hostname
However, it was sitting there in /etc/resolv.conf
I changed 'search modem' to 'search example.com' and it worked instantly.

Comment: The setting can sometimes be pushed by the DHCP server.  In case you find yourself in the same situation later, you can set the DHCP server to provide `example.com` as the search domain, or you can tell the DHCP client not to update `resolv.conf`.  Exact method depends on the DHCP client, but typically involves an empty function in `dhclient-exit-hooks.d`.